# JQuery UI Dialog Scrollbars not Showing on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-dialog, scrollbars

I have a modal dialog set on an iframe using JQuery UI showing a separate page. When the page content height is bigger than the dialog height the scrollbars kind of show up in Firefox although a bit far to the right, when I use Internet Explorer 8 or Chrome they do not show tho. My code goes as follows:

Libraries caller code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Code to open the dialog in a separate .js file:

```
function showRegDialog(url) {
    idNro = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1500) + 1);

    $(function () {

        var horizontalPadding = 0;
        var verticalPadding = 0;

        $('<iframe id="externalSite' + idNro + '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" padding="0" margin="0" style="overflow:auto" class="externalSite" src="' + url + '" />').dialog({
            open: function () {
                $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
            },
            title: false,
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 750,
            height: 700,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            autoResize: false,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: "black"
            }

        }).width(550).height(700);

    });
}
```

The opener page has:

```
<style type="text/css">       
html {overflow : visible} 
</style>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:showRegDialog('view_edit.aspx?c=1');"> Edit<img src="images/btn/edit_pv.png" align="Absbottom" border="0"/></a>                
</li>
</ul>
<!--...-->
</body>
```

The separate content page has:

```
<style type="text/css">       

.viewEdit
{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}

.viewEditForm
{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px
}

.viewEditMainDiv
{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px
}

</style>    

<body class="viewEdit" style="overflow-x:hidden">
<form id="form1" class="viewEditForm">
<div class="viewEditMainDiv">
<!--...-->
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

How can I make those scrollbars show on IE and Chrome?. I have done a decent amount of research and seems that `overflow:visible` or `overflow:auto` would do the trick but this hasn't worked for me yet. Could it be a bug on jquery-ui version if so How can I fix it?.

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As silly as it looks I changed the `scrolling="no"` property of the rendered iframe to `scrolling="yes"` and it solved it.

```
function showRegDialog(url) {

idNro = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1500) + 1);
$(function () { var horizontalPadding = 0;
var verticalPadding = 0;

$('<iframe id="externalSite' + idNro + '" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" padding="0" margin="0" style="overflow:auto" class="externalSite" src="' + url + '" />').dialog({
                open: function () {
                    $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
                },
                title: false,
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 750,
                height: 700,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                autoResize: false,
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    background: "black"
                }    
            }).width(550).height(700);    
        });
}
```

Thank you.